# Error 404 page not found codeigniter 4 after upload to server

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I've problem after upload my project to server,

> 404 page not found

but if i call with url `mydomain.com/public` default controller and page welcome is showing, but I can't call other controller. I've tried to search on google but it still doesn't work, all filenames in controllers and controllers classes already use uppercase, I've also added the `.htaccess` file in folder `public_html`.

1. This is my `.htaccess` file

`RewriteEngine On  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

2. This is my structure folder in `public_html`

   - app
   - public
   - system
   - writable
   - `.env`
   - `.gitignore`
   - `.htaccess`
   - `composer.json`
   - `phpunit.xml.dist`
   - README.md
   - spark

Thank you

Comment: Where is your index page? It should be on the public_html folder but, guessing from your question you might have it on public folder which is within your project so it can be found. 404 means not found. Check that.

Comment: my index.php in folder public

Answer (score 0):

Direct the domain to the public folder. It should load the installation without entering 'mydomain.com/public'. Just enter 'mydomain.com'. Also, make sure your writeable folder and all its subfolders are all writeable.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a confusion as you have a public folder in your project and the server root directory is also named public_html. So, I would create an index page at the root directory, which is public_html, just to redirect the petitions to where the real index page is located, in your case, public directory within your project. Then you just need to call mydomain.com. That's the way I do it all the time and works perfectly.

Create a new index file in public_html folder and place a javascript like this one `<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function () { window.location.href= 'public/index.php'; }, 10);</script>`

The 10 is the amount of time in milliseconds between the call and the real redirection.
This will redirect the petition to the index.php in public folder. The rest of the html code could be empty and you may want to change the background color just to match with your real project so there's no flashing or brusque change between the two index pages.

As a reference you can visit my own website in which the index page will welcome you is completely out of the ionic code which I used to build it. https://www.simbiosis-dg-apps.com. The difference would be that the redirection in mine is done via an user click which will take him/her to English or Spanish version. But it's the same.

Let me clearify it for you. Will say that don't know anything in `php` so you will have to add that part. But in plain html it will look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=160dpi, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
        <title>Your title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="your-description"/>
        <link href="your-css-folder/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body style="background:#your-background-color">
    <script>
    setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href= 'public/index.php';
    }, 10);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I've moved the `index.php` file from the `public` to `public_html` but an error appears **This page isn’t working mydomain.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 –**

Comment: I didn't change index.php from default codeigniter 4

Comment: The problem is that if you move the index file then you break the internal links to which that page target to.

Comment: hi @simbiosis thx for your answer, but my url now looks like `mydomain.com/public/index.php` or `mydomain.com/public/`. also I can't call other controller, the page that appears 404 not found.

Comment: If you do as I said your domain will be `mydomain.com` nothing else as the index.php is going to be included by default in any primary request.

Comment: this is my index.php in `public_hmtl` folder,
`<?php
?>
<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function () { window.location.href= 'public/index.php'; }, 10);</script>`, this my [website](https://kirimbareng.boma.co.id/) . and I have controller Hello.php that I can't call

Comment: I've also tried changing `index.php` to `index.html`, and using the code you provided, but nothing changes

Comment: Then I don't know what happens. Have you tried on a local server? Has it work locally?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the above issue you should following those below steps:

1. Copy the **index.php** and **.htaccess** files from the `public/` directory.
2. Add the files to the root project directory.
3. Change your root project directory **index.php** file `$pathsPath = realpath(FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php');` into  `$pathsPath = realpath(FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php');`

Here is the full code of index.php file:

```
// Valid PHP Version?
$minPHPVersion = '7.2';
if (phpversion() < $minPHPVersion)
{
    die("Your PHP version must be {$minPHPVersion} or higher to run CodeIgniter. Current version: " . phpversion());
}
unset($minPHPVersion);

// Path to the front controller (this file)
define('FCPATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Location of the Paths config file.
// This is the line that might need to be changed, depending on your folder structure.
$pathsPath = realpath(FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php');
// ^^^ Change this if you move your application folder

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * BOOTSTRAP THE APPLICATION
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * This process sets up the path constants, loads and registers
 * our autoloader, along with Composer's, loads our constants
 * and fires up an environment-specific bootstrapping.
 */

// Ensure the current directory is pointing to the front controller's directory
chdir(__DIR__);

// Load our paths config file
require $pathsPath;
$paths = new Config\Paths();

// Location of the framework bootstrap file.
$app = require rtrim($paths->systemDirectory, '/ ') . '/bootstrap.php';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * LAUNCH THE APPLICATION
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * Now that everything is setup, it's time to actually fire
 * up the engines and make this app do its thang.
 */
$app->run();
```